# Does running faster burn more calories?

Tags: running, speed

Imagine this, you have two running courses with the exact same distance, let's say, 2 km. You have the exact same environmental conditions, so the same air temp, sun, etc. You also have the same incline and everything. One course you run 7 km/h, and the other at 10 km/h. Would one course burn more energy, or are they both the same, but the faster one saves time?

Answer (score 2):

Running speed is one of factor to burn calories. According to your scenario, I think running speed it worthy. However if you want to burn more calories from running. you should have to change a pattern of running at least twice per week.